# Can I make a razor file optionally be a template file (RenderBody or RenderSection)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

When I have `RenderBody` or `RenderSection`, and I try to use a template directly, it gives an error:

> The file "~/Views/Home/Form.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderSection" method.

I have a form that has some basic fields, but in one instance, I want to extend the form with more fields (the Model inherits from the original).

Maybe I should just create the basic fields in a shared file, but this would work if it wouldn't throw the error above...

Comment: The question about getting rid of the error message still stands, but I think my solution at this time is just use this as a true partial instead of a layout page. I won't include the `@using(Html.BeginForm())`, but just have the fields, and the master pages can have the `BeginForm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Razor, everything is a view. "Partial views" are just views that don't utilize a layout, while the more traditional "views" are views that do. A "layout" is merely a view that at least calls one method, `RenderBody`. `RenderSection`, is likewise layout-specific. By making a view a layout (by calling methods like `RenderBody`, `RenderSection`, etc., it can no longer be used as "view" or "partial". This has to do with the way Razor handles view processing. By the time something like a partial is being rendered, there's nothing that can be done with something like `RenderBody`, so Razor raises an exception.

Long and short, you can't use a layout as a partial, which seems to be what you're trying to do here. Without more information about what it is that you're actually trying to achieve, it's not really possible to help you further than that.

Comment: Thanks, Chris! I didn't know if there was a solution to this, but my comment on the question states my workaround.